# get subset of elements from set in circular way

Tags: java, algorithm

Consider a set with like 100 elements.

```
Set<String> originalSet; //[1....100] size is 100
```

From originalSet, (m) subset of elements of some size(n) with some starting index(i) have to retrieved.

Example:

```
m = 4, n = 45, i = 1
```

Following have to be retrieved

```
subset1[1-45], subset2[46-90], subset3[91-35], subset4[36-80]
```

Whats the best way of doing this.

Comment: What do you mean "best"?

Comment: `Set` doesn't have a `get` method defined anywhere; you wouldn't be able to take from an arbitrary index since there's no guarantee provided by the `Set` interface that your backing set will *have* an index to take from.

Comment: best as in like which datastructure in java provides subset methods in circular way or any other datastructures from guava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your set has some notion of order, you could write this with

```
Iterable<Iterable<String>> slices = 
   Iterables.limit(
       Iterables.partition(
           Iterables.skip(
               Iterables‌​.cycle(originalSet),
               i),
           n),
       m);
```

If you wanted a set out of this, you'd have to do a `transform` or something; if you have Java 8 that'd just be something like `Iterables.transform(..., ImmutableSet::copyOf)`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `Set` is unordered so it does not make sense to talk about indices etc. `List` would make more sense here.

Next, you have to be explicit about what you mean by "best". Performance on insertion? Random access? Creation of your n-from-i subset? These are important question to choose the implementation.

I think two primary options would be linked list with special handling of the last element in `subList` operation or an array-based list.